# How to know if the result of BigQuery job expired?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BigQuery jobs store their result in a temporary table. According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#temporary_and_permanent_tables), temporary tables exist for up to 24 hours. However, jobs exist for up to 6 months according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#list_jobs_in_a_project) again. So it means we can see job metadata for 6 months, but its results for only 24 hours.

What I'm wondering, is, is there an API call, that, when given a job, can determine if its result is still available or not?

My only lead is by checking if its end date (in its status statistics) is less than 24 hours old. But I was wondering if there was a better way of getting this information.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is a good information to narrow your search (you are sure that after 24 hours, you no longer have the tables). But it's not enough to be sure that the result exists.

So, in fact, BigQuery store job result in a temporary table. You can get [this table in the job information (destination table)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationquery). So, you have to perform a get on the table fully qualified name and if you have a HTTP200 answer, that means the result is still available.

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried this idea too. But it seems the table FQN is always the same if the same query is executed. So, if after 24 hours, a Job 2 runs the same query as the Job 1, it will store its result in the same temporary table. However, a Read() operation on the Job 1 won't return any result, though the Job 2 does. So, I think, internally, BQ has another way of determining which job can access a temporary table or not. Thus, knowing if the temporary table exists or not is not sufficient information to determine if the Read() operation will succeed or just end up time outing.

Comment: I guess BigQuery use a hash of your request to determine the temp table name. So, the combination of timestamp and test the table existance should work, together